# Bash find and replace a record in file with awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm searching a way to replace a record found with awk with a new record directly in a file.

```
cat file

    public function method1()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    /**
     * old comment
     */
    public function oldMethod()
    {
        return 'old';
    }

    public function method3()
    {
        return 3;
    }
```

awk therefore returns

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n\n"; IGNORECASE=1} /oldMethod/ {print $0}' file
    /**
      * old comment
      */
    public function oldMethod()
    {
        return 'old';
    }
```

UPDATE expected output e.g.:

```
cat file

    public function method1()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    /**
     * new comment
     */
    public function newMethod()
    {
        /*Do some fancy stuff here*/
        return 'another output';
    }

    public function method3()
    {
        return 3;
    }
```

Now I want to replace this method with a method contained in a variable.
I have no idea how to achieve that.
Has anyone a good idea?

Best Regards
nTOXIC

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Updated my request with an example output after replacing the oldMethod()

Comment: Updated examples to make clear that is isnt a question about just replacing parts of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is:

```
awk -v new="$var" -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/oldMethod/{$0=new}1' file
```

See:

```
var=$(cat << '_EOF_'
/**
 * new comment
 */
public function newMethod()
{
    /*Do some fancy stuff here*/
    return 'another output';
}
_EOF_
)
```

.

```
$ awk -v new="$var" -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/oldMethod/{$0=new}1' file 
public function method1()
{
    return 1;
}

/**
 * new comment
 */
public function newMethod()
{
    /*Do some fancy stuff here*/
    return 'another output';
}

public function method3()
{
    return 3;
}
```

Just change `/oldMethod/` to however much of the old record you want to search on if it needs to be more than that. If you want to specify that in a variable too just change the command line to:

```
awk -v new="$var" -v old="oldMethod" -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '$0~old{$0=new}1' file
```

For comparison with @anishane's answer, if you had the "new" record in a file instead of a variable all you'd need is:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==FNR{new=$0;next} /oldMethod/{$0=new}1' newfile.c input.c
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat input.c

public function method1()
{
    return 1;
}

/**
 * old comment
 */
public function oldMethod()
{
    return 'old';
}

public function method3()
{
    return 3;
}
```

-

```
$ cat newfile.c
/**
 * new comment
 */
public function newMethod()
{
    /*Do some fancy stuff here*/
    return 'another output';
}
```

-

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS=$'\n' 'NR==FNR{a=a $0 "\n"; next;}/oldMethod/{print ORS a; next;}1' newfile.c input.c

public function method1()
{
    return 1;
}

/**
 * new comment
 */
public function newMethod()
{
    /*Do some fancy stuff here*/
    return 'another output';
}

public function method3()
{
    return 3;
}
```

Explanation:

1. `-v RS=` Set RS to empty string: means separate records by empty lines.
2. `-v ORS=$'\n'` Output record separator.
3. `'NR==FNR{a=a $0 "\n"; next;}'` Capture first file in a variable named `a`. Move to next record.
4. `'/oldMethod/{print ORS a; next;}1'` For record matching /pattern/, print `a`. Else print record.
5. `newfile.c` is the first file. `input.c` is the 2nd file in argument list.

Comment: Why are you setting `ORS=$'\n'` when that's it's default value? Why do you sometimes use an explicit `"\n"` in the text and other times `ORS`? Why are you trying to append to `a` (`a=a $0 "\n"`) when the whole of `newfile.c` will be read as one record? This is very confusing code... I added a simpler version to the end of my answer.

Comment: @EdMorton: `"Why are you trying to append to a (a=a $0 "\n") when the whole of newfile.c will be read as one record"`: It's true in this case. Not necessarily always true. OP may want to extend the newfile.c to contain more functions...

Comment: but then we'd need a very different solution based on whatever his new requirements would be for how to find which functions to replace with which of the new functions. IHMO it's extremely unlikely that the solution even then would include `a=a $0 "\n"` but it's speculation.

Comment: For now I'm using this script to fix a specific method and introduce some custom functions allowing me to decide whether the fix shall be used or not. Because the file gets overwritten all the time the automated system is updating its vendor components it is indeed the easiest way handling all new lines included to the file as a single record and just searching for the method name. So even if the file has not been overwritten by the system, all new lines and the ones to be fixed getting overwritten. So I'm using kind of a mix of both answers ^^